# In Perl, how can I verify that every child of Parallel::ForkManager finishes its job?

Tags: perl, error-handling

I'm working on a Perl program that utilizes [Net::FTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) and [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Parallel-ForkManager-1.03/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm). Within each of the child processes I create with ForkManager, I'm calling a number of Net::FTP methods.  Unfortunately, these sporadically fail, I believe due to connectivity issues.

In the Net::FTP docs, they make it clear that you can/should handle failed method calls like so:

```
$ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0) or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";
```

This works fine to detect errors, but kills my child process in ForkManager.  This is making it very difficult for me to make sure that each child runs to completion or tries again until it succeeds.

What I'm trying to do, is if a Net::FTP method fails, both warn (with a similar message to the die message above) *and* `return 0` from within a subroutine.  My thinking is that this will allow me to reconnect to the FTP and try again, without killing my child process.  Like so (this is just a code snippet):

```
foreach my $page (sort (keys %pages)) {
    my $pid = $pm1->start($page) and next;
    my $ok;
    my $attempts = 1;
    while (!($ok)) {
        print "Attempts on $page: $attempts\n";
        $ok = ftp_server_process($page);
        $attempts++;
    }
    $pm1->finish;
}
```

With the related subroutine:

```
sub ftp_server_process {
    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.ip", Debug => 0, Passive => 1, BlockSize => 1048576) or warn "Cannot connect to some.ip for page $page: $@" and return 0;
    $ftp->login("username", "password") or warn "Cannot login to some.ip\n", $ftp->message and return 0;
    $ftp->binary or warn "opening binary mode failed\n", $ftp->message and return 0;
    $ftp->cwd($ftp_input_folder) or warn "changing directory failed\n", $ftp->message and return 0;
    $ftp->put($pages{$page}{"ftp_upload_name"}) or warn "putting page $page failed\n", $ftp->message and return 0;
    $ftp->quit;
    return 1;
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to approach this problem?  Is the `object->method or warn "a message" and return 0;` syntax correct, or is there an issue there that I'm missing?  It seems to be working well, but it feels shaky and I'm wondering if there's a more established pattern to solve the problem of making sure every child process survives until the job is done.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler to `die` and catch the exception.

```
for my $page (sort keys %pages) {
    $pm->start($page) and next;

    my $attempts_left = 3;
    LOOP: {
        if (!eval { ftp_server_process($page); 1 }) {
           warn $@;
           if (--$attempts_left) {
              warn "Retrying...\n";
              redo;
           } else {
              warn "Aborting.\n";
              $pm->finish(1);
           }
        }
    }

    $pm->finish(0);
}
```

If you so desire, you can even keep note of which one failed in the parent process:

```
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit_code, $page, $signal) = @_;
   if ($exit_code || $signal) {
      print "Couldn't put page $page: ";
      if ($exit_code) {
         print "Exited with $exit_code\n";
      } else {
         print "Killed by signal $signal\n";
      }
   }
);
```